# Single html template for multiple components in Angular

Tags: angular

There are multiple pages in an angular app, that are largely the same, but with few minor differences. Let's say they all have a table, few different buttons on top of if (with specific functionality related to them) and so on.

My instinct for solving this is to have one component containing all the common functionality, extract the differences outside of the component and use content projection to inject it into the view.

Today I saw a the following solution that just feels wrong and is making me a bit nervous for some reason:

An abstract PageComponent class, without component decorator, just the common functionality in it, with page-component.html, that was used as a templateUrl in ***n*** other components that extended the PageComponent class.

This is mostly the same as what I would've done, apart from the fact that a single html file is used as templateUrl in multiple components.

Since 'this feels wrong' isn't really an argument I could make against this, my question is, have you ever seen such approach used in angular applications. Are you aware of any downsides / ramifications that come with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same way of thinking, and i'm gonna tell you what i did for tables then build your solution on that.

First of all lets collect what we need about `mat-table`;

- List of objects as data
- List of columns to show

Lets start with data:

Instead of pass a `matTableDataSource`, i'll declare a variable called `dataSource` to use it for the table, and an input with setter function called `list` to assign user list to `dataSource`:

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
@Input() 
set list(value: Object[]) {
    if(!value) return;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(value);
    // here you can reassign matSort and matPaginator of the dataSource 
}
```

For columns (in my case) i always needed an index column for numbering with options column for row buttons; so i'll pass only the other columns:

I'll declare a variable called `displayedColumns` for the table, another called `userColumns` to make an `ngFor` using it and an input called `columns`:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = [];
userColumns: string[] = [];
@Input()
set columns(value: string[]) {
    if(!value) return;
    this.userColumns = value;
    // assign index as first column and options as last one
    this.displayedColumns.push('index', ...value, 'options');
}
```

BTW; i assumed that each column represent an property in the data elements, like: if i passed a column called `name` so i the value of that column will be `element.name`; but you can make it better by passing a list of objects like:

```
{
    colHeader: 'EmployeeName',
    colValue: 'name'
}
```

and in columns setter you use:

```
let headers = value.map(col => col.colHeader);
this.displayedColumns.push('index', ...headers, 'options');
```

What about row buttons? how can we make it dynamic?

You can use [ng-container](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/) for that purpose; so you will expect parent component to pass a template and you will pass the row as a variable like:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="index">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index"> {{index + 1}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let column of userColumns" [matColumnDef]="column">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="options">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let index = index">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="rowBtns;context: element;">
      </ng-container>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

then pass the buttons in the parent component like:

```
<reusable-table-selector>
    <ng-template #rowBtns let-element>
    <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon>
            edit
        </mat-icon>
    </button>
    </ng-template>
</reusable-table-selector>
```

I hope you read about ngContainer in the link above to avoid errors.

You can enhance that way but i'm giving you a general idea.

I've tried to be helpful, have a nice day.